# Download Apple developer documentation as PDF files

Tags: macos, ios, documentation

There used to be an option in Apple's developer documents, to download guides as PDF files. Not sure if this is guide specific.

For example, this one [Introduction to System Configuration Programming Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_Intro/SC_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH201-TPXREF101) has no download option.

How can I download it?

Comment: Are you certain it is *that* page? It's updated 10 years ago..

Comment: don't know if this page had download option. otherwise, yes that's page I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever be the reason, Apple has stopped providing PDF copies of most of it's Developer Documentation.

This won't work for all pages, but for your specific document, a PDF copy definitely used to exist (shown by [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2113630/5256246)).

The PDF itself is no longer available from Apple servers, but a quick Google search brought up [this archived copy on CiteSeerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.363.8909&rank=1).

Whether you trust it is not modified or edited in any way is up to you ([VirusTotal seems to](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/cd7c5fb803c8b0213550f055ba699d5670536310c9e0a3d35341f8e3f0a9d08a/analysis/1458811448/) [say it's safe](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9fdb701ad8cfffe86993fdc256c22d9146f5998e0aed05e82683a4ffb87ee764/analysis/1458811451/)).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the option you was looking for but you can "print the page to PDF". So just start your print-task as you would usually do and then click "Save to PDF" when selecting a printer.

If you're on Windows, you could use [CutePDF-writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) to perform this task for you.

I've tested this for you, the printing option is very friendly for your page and margins.